# Writing Controller and View in Spring MVC - Having a form with fields which are domain objects

Tags: spring-mvc

I a newbie in Spring MVC. I couldn't find a way to do that:

Suppose, I have a domain class.

```
class CourseRegistration {
  Student student; // Have id and name
  Course course; // Have id and name
  String semester;
}
```

I want to create a spring form to create a course registration.

The course is selected by a combobox populated by the controller.

The student name will be written to a text field, but there is a service to find a user by its name.

How can I write such a controller and view?

- You can assume I have appropriate Business Services for Student, Course, and CourseRegistration.

Comment: Mapping to domain objects now can be done automatically by Spring Data using DomainClassConverter, you must provide String from JSP form as id of the domain object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, define the model underlying the form. Must be a POJO.

A registration will hold: username and course (add whatever you want).

```
class RegistrationModel{
    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private Course course;

    // getters and setters
}
```

The controller

```
@RequestMapping("/registration/**")
@Scope("session")
@Controller
class RegistrationController{
    @Autowired  // or inject manually in app context
    private courseService;

    @Autowired  // or inject manually in app context
    private studentService;

    // No need for getter and setter. However is a best practice to write them
    // Storing the mode in the controller will allow you to reuse the same
    // model between multiple posts (for example, validation that fails)
    private RegistrationModel registrationModel; 

    // getters and setters as usual

    // inject into the view the course list
    // there are other ways to do that, 
    // i'll get my preferred one. 
    // refer to Spring online documentation
    @ModelAttribute("courses")
    public List<Course> injectCourses(){
        return courseService.findAll();
    }

    // create and inject the registration model
    @ModelAttribute("registration")
    public RegistrationModel injectRegistration(){
        if(registrationModel==null)
            registrationModel = new RegistrationModel();

        return registrationModel;
    }

    // handles the post
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView doRegistration(@Valid @ModelAttribute("registration") registration, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasError())
            return new ModelAndView("registration/index"); // redraw the form

        CourseRegistration cr = new CourseRegistration(); // or get it as a bean from the context
        cr.setStudent(studentService.findByUsername(registrationModel.getUsername()));
        cr.setCourse(registrationModel.getCourse());

        courseService.save(cr);

        return new ModelAndView("registration/confirm"); // imaginary path... 
    }

    // "draws" the form
    @RequestMapping
    public ModelAndView registration(){
        return new ModelAndView("registration/index"); // the path is hypothetic, change it
    }

}
```

The JSPX (excerpt of the form)

```
<form:form modelAttribute="registration" method="POST">
    <form:input path="username" />
    <form:errors path="username" />
    <form:select path="course">
        <c:foreach items="${courses}" var="course">
            <form:option value="${course}" label="${course.name [the property to be shown in the drop down]}" />
        </c:foreach>
    </form:select>
    <form:errors path="course" />
</form:form>
```

You'll need to import the following namespaces:

`http://www.springframework.org/tags/form`

`http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core`

(check them)

I have added code for model validation. It should be a good idea to implement a validator of your own to check student existance. Just Google for "JSR 303 spring validation" and you'll find a bunch of resources.

This should be a good backbone to start with.

And... don't trust code correctness. I wrote it on the fly based on what I can recall without intellisense (God bless intellisense! :-) ).

Stefano